# Where is the relevant .desktop file?

Tags: .desktop, xdg, xdg-open

I can open a Python source file using `xdg-open`, e.g.,

```
$ xdg-open Documents/tmp/paramk.py
Waiting for Emacs...
$
```

what happens is that `emacsclient` is invoked and `xdg-open` returns when I close the Emacs' frame.

Out of curiosity I tried

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype Documents/tmp/paramk.py
text/x-python
$ xdg-mime query default text/x-python
userapp-emacsclient-CHYLDY.desktop
$
```

Always curious, I wanted to know the details of the `emacsclient` invocation but …

```
$ locate userapp-emacsclient-CHYLDY.desktop
$ apt-file search userapp-emacsclient
$
```

My question: what trick the desktop system is doing behind my back?

---

*Addendum*

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid \n \l

$
```

Comment: I also curious who and how `userapp-*` desktop entries is generated. `userapp-*` seems like special desktop entries which most of the case are hidden. I use `rofi` launcher manager and it's not showed. However, seems like `userapp-*` desktop entries are registered in `mimeinfo.cache` via `update-desktop-database` command if `MimeType` is specified which make it default opener for certain files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find the file in one of these folders:

- `/usr/share/applications`
- `/usr/local/share/applications`
- `~/.local/share/applications`

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries for reference.

Comment: Thank you, it's in `~/.local/share/applications`. I'd wait a couple of day in the hope of a more complete discussion before accepting your answer.
`

Comment: A couple of days, a couple of years, what a difference does it make? Accepted, finally!